# Hide methods from a subclass that was implicitly derived from (C++)

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Ladies and Gentlemen,

Please see below for the coded example (which is running source code). My question is about making this example more elegant.

What this code is about: I have a class `CRTP` that decorates it's derived class `DT` by injecting function(s) `func` into the derived class. This derived class(es) being `A` and `B`. Additionally `B` also derives from `A`. This will result an ambiguitiy upon compilation, when trying to resolve which `func()` method to call, when looking at expression `b.func()`. To resolve this ambiguity, the `using CRTP< B >::func` is needed to be added to class `B`. Also note that due to the return type of the `func` method it's always the `DT` type being returned.

My question is: Is there any easier / quicker way to "ignore" or "disable" those parts brought into class `B` by indirect inheritance from `CRTP< A >`, than to explicitly employ a `using` phrase for every one of `CRTP< A >`'s methods? (Imagine that `CRTP` will have many more methods (and possibly types) that it will add to it's `DT` class).

Many thanks for your time and insight

```
#include <iostream>

template< typename DT >
struct CRTP 
{
    DT func( void ) { return DT(); }
};

struct A :
    public CRTP< A > 
{
    int get() { return value; }
    private:
        int value = 4;
};

struct B :
    private A
    , public CRTP< B > 
{
    using CRTP< B >::func;
    double get() { return value; }
    private:
        double value = 1.1;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    std::cout << " a: " << a.get() << " b: " << b.get() << std::endl;
    A aa = a.func();
    std::cout << " aa: " << aa.get() << std::endl;
    B bb = b.func(); 
    std::cout << " bb: " << bb.get() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question, but does this answer help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259303/share-instance-of-base-class-for-indirect-base-classes-possible ?

Comment: @MicroVirus: you misundertood, the issue is the method being overloaded (and hiding); not any sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, no. Your approach is the best C++ has got. There's no way to "ignore" the parts brought in through the indirect inheritance from `CRTP<A>`. When you implement inheritance you're making a strict promise to the compiler that the derived class will in fact contain the public and protected functionality of its base classes.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you painted yourself into a corner using multi-inheritance.

If you can have linear inheritance: `B -> CRTP<B, A> -> A -> CRTP<A>` then you are golden because `CRTP<B, A>::func` will "naturally" hide `A::func` (itself inherited from `CRTP<A>`).

If you always inherit with the same level, it's easy; otherwise it's going to be very complicated. See the [demo](http://ideone.com/dBEQ7j):

```
template< typename DT, typename... Bases >
struct CRTP: private Bases...
{
    friend DT; // so that DT can access the private bases
    DT func( void ) { return DT(); }
};
```